# Django - Defining a child class inside a TestCase

Tags: python, django

I am packaging an Django app that I would like to reuse (and hopefully can be used by others), and I would like to create a test case that mimics defining a child class when the app is used in different contexts.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227829/defining-a-one-off-class-within-python-unittest) to do something similar in a Python test case, however, I am getting the following error for my Django test case.

```
RuntimeError: Model class tests.test_unit_health.Heart doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Below is similar to what I have setup that is generating this error:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class HealthTest(models.Model):
    # some attributes...
    # some methods...
    def get_score(self, **kwargs):
        score = self.score(**kwargs)
        # more logic
```

test_unit_health.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from health.models import HealthTest


class HealthTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        class Heart(HealthTest):
            def score(self, heartrate):
                if heartrate > 90:
                    return 2
                else:
                    return 1
```

The full error looks like this:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.test_unit_health (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.test_unit_health
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File ".../test_unit_health.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Heart(HealthTest):
  File ".../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 118, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class tests.test_unit_health.Heart doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Any help getting this to work is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#isolating-model-registration - this one could help I think.
PS also have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#app-label

Comment: Thanks @sepulchered! I ended up modifying the app_label using the second link and that solved my issue. Since I was defining the same child class in separate tests, I had to exception handle due to the child class attempting to define itself more than once. I suppose this has the potential to cause confusion if I configured the logic in 'score' differently, but for my purposes this worked perfectly.